# PHP preg_split keeping delimiter in a different element

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a string into an array of parts.

String Example...

```
The quick brown fox [[random text here]] and then [[a different text here]]
```

Text between the square brackets will change and cannot be determined ahead of time. The preg_split I have so far will split, but it places the delimiters in other elements in the produced array, not the element I want it to be in.

```
$page_widget_split = preg_split('@(?<=\[\[)(.*?)(?=\]\])@', $page_content,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

This produces something like this...

```
[0] => "The quick brown fox [[",
[1] => "random text here]]",
[2] => " and then [[",
[3] => "a different text here]]"
```

The desired result would look like this...

```
[0] => "The quick brown fox",
[1] => "[[random text here]]",
[2] => " and then ",
[3] => "[[a different text here]]"
```

As I'm far from understanding Regex, could someone please take a look and tell me what I'm missing in the regex ?

Comment: Nope...error in my typo..fixed...problem still exists tho.

Comment: A great way of testing regex would be https://regex101.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you pretty close

```
 $page_content = 'the quick brown fox [[random text here]] and then [[a different text here]]';

 print_r(preg_split('/(\[\[[^\]]+\]\])/', $page_content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

The thing to remember is that this is the delimiter `(\[\[[^\]]+\]\])`

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => the quick brown fox 
    [1] => [[random text here]]
    [2] =>  and then 
    [3] => [[a different text here]]
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ddd4d54a7f62e76285d8daf041afc7dfc6d83cf9)

When i say `pretty close`, I do mean really pretty close...

The regex is pretty straight forward, capture 2 `[` then anything but a `]` then 2 of those `]`.  Which makes our delimiter, which we then capture.  No empty flag is nice too.

Enjoy!

**UPDATE**

> but it fails on " here is my table [[{"widget":"table","id":"1","title": "Views Table", "columns": []}]] and this is more text"...Note the "[]" under the 'columns'

To handle that you will need a recursive regex pattern using `(?R)`, like this:

```
$page_content = 'here is my table [[{"widget":"table","id":"1","title": "Views Table", "columns": []}]] and this is more text [someother bracket]';

print_r(preg_split('/(\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?R))*\])/', $page_content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => here is my table 
    [1] => [[{"widget":"table","id":"1","title": "Views Table", "columns": []}]]
    [2] =>  and this is more text 
    [3] => [someother bracket] //single bracket capture
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8966ea46a978a8eb96ebea8ec90636aa17c32ce)

I won't pretend, this is kind of at the edge of my knowledge of regex, I should note this matches single brackets and not specifically double ones.  You could try something like this `/(\[(\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?2))*\])\])/` the `(?2)` is like `(?R)` but for a specific capture group.  Which this works to match only `[[ ... ]]` while keeping the inner nesting.  But the issue is, then you have the capture duplicated, so you wind up with this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => here is my table 
    [1] => [[{"widget":"table","id":"1","title": "Views Table", "columns": []}]]
    [2] => [{"widget":"table","id":"1","title": "Views Table", "columns": []}]
    [3] =>  and this is more text [someother bracket]
)
```

Notice how it doesn't capture `[someother bracket]`, but it captures the other one 2 times.  There may be a way around that, but i can't think of it.

Rather or not capturing single bracket pairs is an issue I don't know.

But I have used this before, mainly for matching, matched pairs of `"` or `( )` but it's the same concept.

The only other solution would be to make a lexer/parser for it, I have some examples of how do do that on my [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers) account.  Regex (by itself) is not suited to nested elements.  Most any regex solution will fail on nesting.

Comment: Looks like that's working...gunna test a bit more and mark as answer.

Comment: The regex works for an instance like this " here is my table [[{"widget":"table","id":"1","title": "Views Table", "columns": ""}]] and this is more text" but it fails on " here is my table [[{"widget":"table","id":"1","title": "Views Table", "columns": []}]] and this is more text"...Note the "[]" under the 'columns' parameter is meant as an array in the string ? Seems when the regex encounters this in the string, regex returns a negative and continues on without finding this as a valid [[...]]

Comment: Perfect , you're a star mate. One day I'll get my head around regex.

Comment: `One day I'll get my head around regex` it's easy.  You just have to understand it's it's own language, like HTML or SQL

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `preg_match_all` instead, it'll probably make the regex's logic easier to figure out:

```
/\[{2}.+?\]{2}|.+?(?=\[{2}|$)/
```

Alternate between:

- `\[{2}.+?\]{2}`, match `[[`, lazy-repeat characters, followed by matching `]]`, or
- `.+?(?=\[{2}|$)`, lazy-repeat characters until lookahead matches `[[` or the end of the string

https://regex101.com/r/ls6oBa/1

In PHP:

```
$str = "The quick brown fox [[random text here]] and then [[a different text here]] foobar";
preg_match_all('/\[{2}.+?\]{2}|.+?(?=\[{2}|$)/',$str, $result);
```

Comment: This might also be an answer, haven't tested it as I'm looking at the first solution. Thanks.

Comment: This answer does successfully extract the [[...]] matches, but does not return the text outside the [[...]] as well as elements in the array. I need all 'parts' of the string returned as elements in an array split into text sections and [[...]] sections.

Comment: I thought it *did* do that? See the regex101, it extracts `The quick brown fox `, then `[[random text here]]`, then ` and then `, etc? It matches both the `[[..]]` and everything outside of the `[[..]]`s

Comment: As near as I could tell, it doesn't split all the parts of the string into elements in an array, it only extracts the matches. ie. everything inside [[...]] including the brackets, it leaves out the text outside the brackets. Not complaining though, and thanks for teaching me new tricks :)